# Gradle how to use plugin in an included common build script

Tags: gradle, plugins

project A:

```
   apply from : 'common.gradle'
```

common.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.eriwen.gradle.js' version '2.14.1'
}

apply plugin: 'js'

import com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask;

task minify(type: MinifyJsTask) {
   ...
}
```

Error

```
Only Project build scripts can contain plugins {} blocks
```

If the plugins block moved to project A,

Error

```
unable to resolve class com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask
```

How to use an plugin (from public responsitory) in an included build script (called script plugin)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. (I used [this page](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-apply-a-plugin-to-a-project-from-a-shared-applied-gradle-file/7508) as a resource, but not sure if it is still accurate.) With Gradle 4.0:

Given `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: 'common.gradle'
```

here is `common.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:2.14.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: com.eriwen.gradle.js.JsPlugin 

task minify(type: com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How would you use this workaround to apply one of the built-in plugins like `application` or `java-library` ?

Answer (score 0):

When using Gradle's Kotlin DSL the method explained by Michael does not allow to use the type-safe model accessors provided by the plugin(s). Instead you can put your common build script into the `buildSrc` directory structure. This allows the use of the `plugins{}` block and gives you all the advantages of the type-safe Kotlin DSL. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources